# When other apps share with my app, it kind of creates two instances of my app

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an app that works best if the main activity is always the same activity instance, otherwise, it would be very confusing to users. When I first coded this app years ago, the solution I found was to use:

```
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:taskAffinity="somestring"
```

And this works well for the most part, but when some apps share stuff with my app, it is like my app becomes part of their app and now it is like I have two separate instances of my app. If I go to the task switcher and select their app, it will actually go to my app. This works fine with most apps that can share stuff with my app, only some will cause this issue.

How can I get around that issue?

Edit: As it was pointed out, it is not two separate instances but my users think it is, and it is annoying them a lot.

Edit: The issue appears to be when the sharing app uses `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`.

Comment: "now I have two separate instances of my app" -- no, you don't. You have two instances of this activity, in two different tasks.

Comment: Yes but to my users it is very confusing, they think the app is running twice. You see my app is a web browser, so now they are wondering why this shared page isn't on same browser as the one they were using before sharing with it. Does that make sense?

Comment: I assume that by "share stuff with my app", you refer to `ACTION_VIEW` or `ACTION_SEND`. Particularly for the latter, perhaps the `ACTION_SEND` `<intent-filter>` could be on a different `<activity>`, one that uses `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`. That activity, in turn, would forward the `Intent` on to the real activity, but with appropriate flags to route the request to your existing activity (where you would get the `Intent` in `onNewIntent()`).

Comment: The intents are mostly `VIEW`. I just did a test with a sample app and what I think is happening is that they are using `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`. I had thought about doing what you suggest but seems like an ugly hack, is there a better solution now that I know the issue is `startActivityForResult`? Thanks.

Comment: "what I think is happening is that they are using startActivityForResult instead of startActivity" -- that would be strange. `ACTION_VIEW` doesn't return a result. "is there a better solution now that I know the issue is startActivityForResult?" -- nothing comes to mind that is less ugly. FWIW, I filed [a feature request for a Lint check to point out to developers when they use `startActivityForResult()` with an unsuitable action](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73803091).

Comment: This is what I see on the logcat `02-23 15:06:54.279 918-2196/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://someip/... typ=video/* flg=0x3000000 cmp=mypackage/.MyClass (has extras)} from uid 10159`. My app doesn't return any kind of a result anyways so maybe that solution wouldn't be too bad.